# How can I list MMC partitions in a Linux driver?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to read the U-Boot environment that is stored on eMMC, but I can't figure out how I can list the disks. The driver I'm creating is separated of the mmc device driver (/dev/mmcblk0p1).

I already found out that the partitions of `mmcblk0` are [struct mmc_part](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/include/linux/mmc/card.h#L229) entries in [struct mmc_card](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/include/linux/mmc/card.h#L244). Basically I'm searching for the mmc variant of [__mtd_next_device](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/drivers/mtd/mtdcore.c#L89).

---

**EDIT 1:**
I found out that I can get a [block_device](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L432) struct through [bdget](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.17/source/fs/block_dev.c#L517), but `gendisk` points to `NULL`.

```c
struct block_device *my_bdevice;
struct gendisk *my_gdisk;
my_bdevice = bdget(179);
my_gdisk = part_to_disk(my_bdevice->bd_part);
if (!my_gdisk) goto end; // Goes to end..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code above, `my_bdevice = bdget(179);` is wrong:

```c
dev_t devt = blk_lookup_devt("mmcblk0", 0);
my_bdevice = bdget(devt);
```